# How to call grandparent method in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I need to override Parent method and call Grandparent method with NodeJs. Is it possible?

For example: `A` and `B` are library classes.

```
class A {
   printFunction() {
       console.log('Hello');
   }
}

class B extends A {
   printFunction() {
       console.log('World');
   }
   runFunction() {
       console.log('Running');
   }
}
```

Now I have a class `C` which extends class `B`.

```
class C extends B {
     // can i call class A printFunction here?
}
```

In the class C, can i call `printFunction` of A?

Comment: Write the code and see if it calls the function - then you'll know.

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: If i call `printfunction` in class C it will call the function of class B. is there way to call function of class A?

Comment: @rijin I want to use most of logic of class B but i want to reuse just one method which is very specific to class B of class A.

Comment: So we're all on the same page here, we should be clear that having to do this indicates a poorly designed class hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the exact function using [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
class C extends B {
  callA() {
    A.prototype.printFunction.call(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: the prototype is an old method. Is there any other option in ES6? I mean to say can we create an instance of class A and then can we use `.call`?

Answer (score 1):

No, not while class C extends class B, because you've already overridden the `printFunction()` in class B. From class C's point of view, it doesn't care what class A's definition of `printFunction()` is because that has now been modified.

The only way to do this would be to have class C extend class A, and redefine any function you require from class B.